# Google charts: Object 2013-07-25 has no method 'getTime

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw a chart with google charts API. One column contains dates, the other one contains numbers.

This is the php page to get my data:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

$result = mysql_query('SELECT amountDone, resultDate FROM result');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Done', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$r['amountDone']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['resultDate']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;

?>
```

The json data returned is the following:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Done","type":"int"},{"label":"Date","type":"date"}],"rows":[{"c":    [{"v":1200},{"v":"2013-07-25"}]},{"c":[{"v":3600},{"v":"2013-07-26"}]}]}
```

In my main page I try to draw the chart with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "get_json.php",
              dataType:"json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
        }

</script>
```

But I always get the following error (depends on the browser I use but they contain the same information I guess, this one is chrome):

```
Object 2013-07-25 has no method 'getTime
```

Anybody an idea what this could mean because I don't get a single other error

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed my query to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(resultDate, '%W, %D %M %Y') as Datum,    SUM(amountDone) as AmountD, SUM(amountToDo) as AmountT
                       FROM result
                       GROUP BY resultDate");
```

and the type is now string. Works like a charm. :)